# Memoization of promise-based function

Tags: javascript, promise, memoization

How can I memoize a promise-based function?

Would straightforward memoization of the function suffice?

```
function foo() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      doSomethingAsync({ success: resolve, fail: reject });
    });
};
```

Would this suffice?

```
var fooMemoized = memoize(foo);
```

**Note:** this question has been updated to remove the deferred anti-pattern.

Comment: Yep, that should work. The first time fooMemoized is called foo() will run and return the promise. Memoize will then 'cache' that promise. Each proceeding call to fooMemoized will return that same promise which if marked as resolved already will fire straight away.

Comment: Please note your anti-pattern in your implementation of `foo()`.  Its entire body could just be `return doSomethingAsync();`

Comment: @jfriend00: s/could/should/ :-) This form of the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) fails to pass errors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, that will suffice. Promises are simple return values, which is their great benefit - in contrast to callbacks, where memoisation code would be horrible.

You only might want to make sure that the memoized promise is uncancellable, if your promise library does support some kind of cancellation. Also notice that this form of memoisation remembers rejections as well, so you can't recover from errors by "trying again".

Answer (score 8):

For promises simple sync memoize will not be good, because in most of cases you will not wish to memoize errors (rejected promises).

I did a simple library for common needs: https://github.com/nodeca/promise-memoize

1. It memoize Promise-based function, except errors by default
2. You can set expiration time for result
3. If you need, you can remember (and set expiration time) for errors too.
4. Data can be prefetched prior to expire, to never leave cache in cold state.

Pseudo code:

```
let db = require('mongoose').createConnection('mongodb://localhost/forum');

function lastPosts(limit) {
  return db.model('Post').find()
    .limit(limit).orderBy('-_id').lean(true).exec(); // <- Promise (thenable)
}

let cachedLastPosts = require('promise-memoize')(lastPosts, { maxAge: 60000 });

// Later...
cachedLastPosts(10).then(posts => console.log(posts));
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! I had tried another ones with NextJS but there were some issues with Edge runtime

Answer (score 2):

Note that your function has the deferred anti pattern and can be simplified further:

```
foo.value = null;
function foo(){
    if(foo.value) return foo.value;
    return (foo.value = doSomethingAsync());
}
```

That is, memoization is so simple in this case you don't even have to call `.memoize`. Also your original function suppressed errors.

Comment: Is this an attempt to comment on @azaviruha answer? Not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't slept in a day. I already upvoted your answer but noticed OP could inline this inside the function

Comment: Hm, I think it's pretty fine to do memoisation using a higher-order function and not to clutter the `foo` logic (as simple as it might be) with it.

Comment: How common is setting a property on a function...I mean doing obj.value = 'x' is commonly seen, but is func.value = 'x' something used practically/commonly?

Comment: Practically yes, commonly not so much.

Answer (score 2):

As @Bergi, and @BenjaminGruenbaum have pointed out, yes memoization is fine here, but it should be pointed out that your `foo` function is doing *nothing* useful and is actually introducing bugs (see: deferred antipattern).

If all you want is to memoize the result of `doSomethingAsync`, then you can cut out the middle-man:

```
var fooMemoized = memoize(doSomethingAsync);
```

Or if you were actually oversimplifying and `foo()` is passing arguments to `doSomethingAsync`, then you can still reduce it to one line:

```
function foo() {
    return doSomethingAsync(argument1, argument2, etc.);
}
var fooMemoized = memoize(foo);
```

Or if you don't actually plan to use `foo()`, you can do:

```
var fooMemoized = memoize(function () {
    return doSomethingAsync(argument1, argument2, etc.);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Memoization and promises aren't obvious. Even worst with the new async / await syntax.

in order to get somewhint like that working:

```
memoize(async () => 42)
```

or

```
const whatsTheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything = () => 42
memoize(whatsTheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything)
```

You need a memoize function or library which supports promises and async syntax. A couple of them:
 - https://github.com/aboutlo/async-memo-ize (Disclosure: I did this lib)
 - https://github.com/medikoo/memoizee

Notice: Memoization is a cool technique however you save CPU resources at the cost of a memory consumption. You should take care how those libraries approach this issue at scale ;)