# Timeout in async/await

Tags: node.js, typescript, timeout, promise, async-await

I'm with Node.js and TypeScript and I'm using `async/await`.
This is my test case:

```
async function doSomethingInSeries() {
    const res1 = await callApi();
    const res2 = await persistInDB(res1);
    const res3 = await doHeavyComputation(res1);
    return 'simle';
}
```

I'd like to set a timeout for the overall function. I.e. if `res1` takes 2 seconds, `res2` takes 0.5 seconds, `res3` takes 5 seconds I'd like to have a timeout that after 3 seconds let me throw an error.

With a normal `setTimeout` call is a problem because the scope is lost:

```
async function doSomethingInSeries() {
    const timerId = setTimeout(function() {
        throw new Error('timeout');
    });

    const res1 = await callApi();
    const res2 = await persistInDB(res1);
    const res3 = await doHeavyComputation(res1);

    clearTimeout(timerId);

    return 'simle';
}
```

And I cannot catch it with normal `Promise.catch`:

```
doSomethingInSeries().catch(function(err) {
    // errors in res1, res2, res3 will be catched here
    // but the setTimeout thing is not!!
});
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: Are you using a specific promise library?

Comment: No, just standard promise.

Comment: So 2 + 0.5 + 5 + 3 makes a timeout of 11.5 seconds?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) to make a timeout:

```
Promise.race([
    doSomethingInSeries(),
    new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), 11.5e3))
]).catch(function(err) {
    // errors in res1, res2, res3 and the timeout will be caught here
})
```

You cannot use `setTimeout` without wrapping it in a promise.

Comment: @nkint: We don't need to clear it because the rejection is not considered when `doSomethingInSeries()` settles first. We could clear it, but that would be rather complicated (optimally `race` would have a way to cancel the slower promises, but that's not possible with native promises).

Comment: Maybe I have problem in testing async stuff but seems to me that even if `race` rejects, doSomethingInSeries keep on going its own stuffs. How to be sure to stop everything inside `doSomethingInSeries` if the timeout rejects?

Comment: @nkint: You cannot stop a promise - it only represents a result (disclaimer: unless you use a promise implementation that supports cancellation). So if there is anything you need to do about the ongoing stuff, you need to do it manually (in the same way you did it with `clearTimeout` in your answer below).

Comment: `it only represents a result` - vary clear, thanks. It's a little bit messy. Some promise I'm `await`-ing in `doSomethingInSeries` is a call to `request` with a retry.. I need some other way to handle it, thank you anyway.

Comment: To have promise-wraped version of `setTimeout` / `clearTimeout` you may have a look on [await-timeout](https://github.com/vitalets/await-timeout)

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found this way:

```
async function _doSomethingInSeries() {
    const res1 = await callApi();
    const res2 = await persistInDB(res1);
    const res3 = await doHeavyComputation(res1);
    return 'simle';
}

async function doSomethingInSeries(): Promise<any> {
  let timeoutId;

  const delay = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
      reject(new Error('timeout'));
    }, 1000);
  });

  // overall timeout
  return Promise.race([delay, _doSomethingInSeries()])
    .then( (res) => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      return res;
    });

}
```

Anyone errors?

The things that smells a bit to me is that using Promises as asynchronicity strategy will send us to allocate too many object that some other strategy needs but this is off-topic.

Comment: You're not clearing the timeout if `_doSomethingInSeries()` fails. You should use `try { return await Promise.race(…); } finally { clearTimeout(timeoutId); }`

Answer (score 2):

Problem with @Bergi answer that `doSomethingInSeries` continues executing even if you already rejected the promise. It is much better to cancel it.

**LATEST ANSWER**

You can try use [AbortController](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) for that. Check the old answer   to see how to use it - api is similar.

Keep in mind that task is not cancelled immediately, so continuation (awaiting, then or catch) is not called exactly after timeout.

To guarantee that you can combine this and @Bergi approach.

**OLD ANSWER**

This is how it should look like:

```js
async const doSomethingInSeries = (cancellationToken) => {
  cancellationToken.throwIfCancelled();

  const res1 = await callApi();

  cancellationToken.throwIfCancelled();

  const res2 = await persistInDB(res1);

  cancellationToken.throwIfCancelled();

  const res3 = await doHeavyComputation(res1);

  cancellationToken.throwIfCancelled();

  return 'simle';
}
```

Here is simple implementation:

```js
const makeCancellationToken = (tag) => {
  let cancelled = false;

  return {
    isCancelled: () => cancelled,
    cancel: () => {
      cancelled = true;
    },
    throwIfCancelled: () => {
      if (cancelled) {
        const error = new Error(`${tag ?? 'Task'} cancelled`);
        error.cancelled = true;
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And finally usage:

```js
const cancellationToken = makeCancellationToken('doSomething')

setTimeout(cancellationToken.cancel, 5000);

try {
  await doSomethingInSeries(cancellationToken);
} catch (error) {
  if (error.cancelled) {
    // handle cancellation
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that task is not cancelled immediately, so continuation (awaiting, then or catch) is not called exactly after 5 secs.

To guarantee that you can combine this and @Bergi approach.