# How to handle an unsettled promise in express

Tags: node.js, express, promise

Is there a recommended way to prevent a promises that doesn't ever settle from blocking an express route?  I came up with this but wanted to know if there are preferable options.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const resultPromise = functionThatGetsAPromiseThatMightNotSettle();
  const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => reject('Timed Out', 10000);
  })

  Promise.race([resultPromise, timeoutPromise])
    .then(res.send)
    .catch(next)
})
```

Comment: [Using `Promise.race` for a timeout is just fine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37120240/1048572), though preferably the function should then also have a way to cancel its task. And of course in general you should never really have a promise that never settles.

Comment: Did you know that express already has a default request timeout built-in?  See https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3330.

Comment: Also `.then(res.send)` will not work as you have it.   You lose the binding to `res`.  You would need `.then(res.send.bind(res))` to fix that.