# Is there a way for a function to return the value of competing promises (like AWAIT does)?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

I'm interested in the case of wrapping an async operation in a timeout for failure to finish.
For example,
I'm trying to get data with a fetch function,
if after 4 seconds it doesn't arrive, have the function return a result indicating the failure.

I tried to figure it out with Promise.race but still couldn't get it to affect the function's return value.

```
async timeoutedAwait(awaitedFunc,timeoutInMs){
  setTimeout(()=>{ /* somehow make the function return {success:false,value:undefined} */},timeoutInMs);
  return await awaitedFunc();
}
//....
let result=timeoutedAwait(someFetchOperationFunc,4000);
if(result.success){/* success handling code */}
else{ /* failure handling code */}
```

Comment: `Promise.race` should do the job. Can you show you attempt with it?

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use `Promise.race`. Also notice that `timeoutedAwait()` still returns a promise when called, you cannot access the `result` immediately (as usual for async functions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timeout in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37120240/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this?

```
async function timeoutedAwait(awaitedFunc,timeoutInMs){
  return await Promise.race([awaitedFunc,fail(timeoutInMs)]);
}

var fail = function (time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, time, {success:false,value:undefined});
 });
}

let result=timeoutedAwait(someFetchOperationFunc,4000);
if(result.success){/* success handling code */}
else{ /* failure handling code */}
```

Comment: Avoid passing `someFetchOperationFunc` and executing it in `timeoutedAwait()`.