# Is there a way to throw an error from a non-awaited promise in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to write a NodeJS script that will return gracefully if it takes too long.

So far I have:

```
async function willTimeout(){
  try{
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(reject, 1, "timeout");
    }).catch(error => {
      throw error;
    });
    await variableLengthFunction()
  }catch{
    //Handle error gracefully here
  }
}
```

This doesn't work because the `.catch()` in the promise doesn't return gracefully as it is an unhandled promise rejection. Is there any way to return an error from a promise that is caught by the encompassing try block?

Comment: Not really, because if it's not awaited it's not part of the same promise chain.

Comment: You don't need to wrap in a try/catch. You should return the promise. Also check out https://github.com/getify/CAF

Comment: you might need to add try/catch for `willTimeout` too. `try { await willTimeout() } catch() {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is exactly [why you don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32384449/1048572).

You have to either `await` it:

```
async function willTimeout() {
  try {
    await somePromise
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle error gracefully here
  }
}
```

or use `.then()`/`.catch()`:

```
function willTimeout() {
  return somePromise.catch(e => {
    // Handle error gracefully here
  });
}
```

> I am trying to write a NodeJS script that will return gracefully if it takes too long.

For that, see [Timeout in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37120240/1048572):

```
async function willTimeout() {
  try {
    return await Promise.race([
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(reject, 1, new Error("timeout"));
      }),
      variableLengthFunction()
    ]);
  } catch(err) {
    // Handle error from `variableLengthFunction` or timeout gracefully here
  }
}
```