# How to stop gracefully a long running transaction in Hana DB

Tags: javascript, database, hana

I am using a hana-client tool from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sap/hana-client
Essentially I have a callback that takes long time so I decide to run it in parallel in `Promise.race` to throw an Error after 1000 ms([Timeout in async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120240/timeout-in-async-await))

This won't break the currently running operation in callback, but I hoped that rollback will terminate it once the `catch` block is reached after 1000 ms.
This rollback doesn't seem to work though and it just waits until the callback will be completed. This blocks a table in my DB for quite some time.

My next idea was to use db.abort() from https://help.sap.com/viewer/f1b440ded6144a54ada97ff95dac7adf/2.12/en-US/b98b880fc6a344aa85ef0b471fa19af4.html
However this also does not seem to break the long taking callback.
Am I doing something wrong?

```js
   try {
      db = await this.acquire();
      db.connection.setAutoCommit(false);
      const wrapper = new HanaClientAsyncWrapper(db);
      await Promise.race([
        callback(wrapper),
        new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(
          async () => {
            reject(new Error("Timeout due to a long-running operation"));
            // await db.abort(); <- does not work
          }, 1000,
        )),
      ]);
      await db.commit();
    } catch (err) {
      if (db) {
        await db.rollback();
      }
      throw err;
    } finally {
      if (db) {
        db.connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        await this.release(db);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping active statements during execution may be delayed in HANA. The internal task management in HANA is a "cooperative" multitasking approach, broadly speaking. And some parts of the query execution engine do not check for a cancellation flag often enough. This is usually the case, when checking for such a flag more often would incur a higher performance cost - and the baseline assumption is to *not* cancel statements.

In case, excessive runtime leads to locks that, in turn, lead to actual application blockages, it may be a good choice to consider using workload management classes for those statement.
See the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_HANA_PLATFORM/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/dc417c30b1b3460c8860f6c7ea2a7faa.html?version=2.0.05&locale=en-US) for details on that.