# Terminate a function that's taking too long

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

So I'm trying to write a function that terminates itself if it runs for longer than *x* number of seconds. I'm not sure why the following logic does not seem to be working:

```js
async function thing() {
    try{
        const tid = setTimeout(()=>{
            throw new Error("took too long");
        }, 10)
        // something that takes time
        await delay(10);
        // filter function
        clearTimeout(tid);
        console.log("Hello world")
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log("Moving on")
    }
}
```

In my head - I keep thinking that the catch block would deal with the error that is being thrown. But that is not what is happening - it, in fact, throws the error and quits instead of "moving on" Im not sure what I am doing wrong precisely, but I would appreciate help in trying to fix this error!

Comment: The callback in`setTimeout` will throw, but that won't interrupt execution of your outer function. JS only runs one synchronous chunk of code at a time, to completion. There's no way to "interrupt"

Comment: Any ideas or hacks of how to go about doing that ?

Comment: You could create your own Promise that rejects after a delay using setTimeout inside the executor. But what is your async task? `fetch`?

Comment: The real solution depends on what the actual code is.

Comment: In the REAL code is this function using actual asynchronous operations that you're waiting for?  If so, this is doable, but we need to see the REAL code, not pseudo-code because there is no generic way to do this - it depends upon the specific asynchronous operations.  If what you're trying to abort is not asynchronous, then there's no way to do that from the outside.  The function itself will just have to keep track of how long its taking and every so often check if too much time has elapsed and then abort itself.

Comment: I find the question pretty clear. The OP provides an async function, `delay`, and would like the wrapping function, `thing()`, to terminate if the delay is too long. They just don't know how to code it.

Comment: @Chris yeah - the delay bit is the code that's doing things - unfortunately, I cannot disclose what that does for various reasons. But essentially, it does an async fetch and some other stuff.

Comment: Well, how exactly you add a timeout to an asynchronous operation depends entirely upon what the asynchronous operation is and how it works.  Some are even cancellable.  Some are not.  Some work with promises, some do not.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120240/timeout-in-async-await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided a callback to `setTimeout` which throws an error. But that callback is executed in a separate part of the event loop, and doesn't communicate back to the rest of your code. To do this right, you should return promises, which your code receives immediately, and you can connect further actions to them. If you're using async/await, throwing an error inside an async function will also reject the promise your function returns. Once you have a returned promise in your code, then you can handle it. Here's an example.

```
// This is the function that you think might take too long.
async function longJob() {
  const result = await new Promise((resolve: any) => 
    setTimeout(() => resolve('job done'), 2 * 1000))
  return result;
}

// This is your timer. It will reject after some time.
async function timer(seconds: number) {
  await new Promise((_resolve, reject: any) =>
    setTimeout(() => reject('took too long'), seconds * 1000))
}

// Combine them with Promise.race, which just acts on the first
// thing that happens. If the timer rejects before the job is
// done, the whole thing rejects.
async function selfTerminating(job: Function) {
  const result = await Promise.race([
    job(),
    timer(1),
  ]);

  return result
}

// You can handle rejections with the .catch() method of a promise.
selfTerminating(longJob)
  .then((result) => console.log('resolved with', result))
  .catch((reason) => console.error('rejected with', reason))

// You can also use try/catch inside an async function.
async function main() {
  try {
    const result = await selfTerminating(longJob);
  } catch (e: any) {
    console.error('Catch block', e);
  }
}
main();
```

I've used a fairly verbose style here to make it clearer that `await` statements return promises. But they're just Promise objects after all, and you could write most of this without using async/await at all.

Comment: Thanks this worked out perfectly for what I was trying to do