# Why doesn't Node.js exit after Promise.race is finished?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I use `Promise.race` to timeout and cancel requests made by the Request-Promise library. My `Promise.race` implementation seems to block the program.

`Promise.race` does resolve and return but after that, the program never exits.

Again, I want to emphasize that the await indeed completes and logs the response but the program never exits.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

/**
 * @param {rp.RequestPromise} request 
 * @param {Number} ms 
 * @returns {Error}
 */
const delay = (request, ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => {
    request.cancel();
    return reject(new Error("Timeout"))
}, ms))

async function main() {
    try {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",
        };

        const request = rp(options);
        const response = await Promise.race([request, delay(request, 500000)]);

        console.log(response)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

main()
```

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: @FZs The point here is that the await completes but the program never exits. It even logs the response. I knew what await does.

Comment: Question is unclear. Never exits? I don't even see `main` being called. I think you got voted up because `Promise.race` is not well known about. Thanks for that.

Comment: @StackSlave I forget to copy that line, edited question to reflect main getting called.

Comment: @StackSlave The main function never exits. I see response getting logged. I think `setTimeout` blocks the function from being exiting.

Comment: `Promise.race` just returns the first `Promise` is resolved or rejected. I don't see any documentation that says the other `Promise` does not resolve, so I think `request.cancel()` in happening, either way.

Comment: @StackSlave Promise resolves. See the answer below, I have to unref the `setTimeout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither is `Promise.race()`, nor `await` the source of the issue. It is `setTimeout`.

Actually, your code does work. One small thing, that it keeps hanging when it is completed. Not forever, only until your timer expires. For some 500 seconds.

Node.js works by tracking all the possible inputs to your program and exits only when there aren't any (or, of course, if exited programmatically via `process.exit()` or manually by sending an interrupt or kill signal to it). However, your `setTimeout` **is** an input; although its completion is a no-op, Node.js doesn't know that, so it keeps the process alive.

To resolve the issue, you can tell Node.js, that the `setTimeout` is not important and that your program may exit regardless of it by `unref`fing it:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

/**
 * @param {rp.RequestPromise} request 
 * @param {Number} ms 
 * @returns {Promise<Error>}
 */
const delay = (request, ms) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    setTimeout(() => {
        request.cancel();
        return reject(new Error("Timeout"))
    }, ms)
    //Call unref on the interval ID object that setTimeout returned
    //Note that this is Node.js only.
    .unref()
)

async function main() {
    try {
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",
        };

        const request = rp(options);
        const response = await Promise.race([request, delay(request, 500000)]);

        console.log(response)

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
}

main()
```

That way, the process will be kept alive only until the request completes; if the timer fires faster, it will cancel the request and therefore exit the program, but if your request finishes first, it may just exit without waiting for the timer.

However, note that such `setTimeout` calls will accumulate (this code doesn't *cancel* the timeout if there's something else in the event loop that keeps the process alive), which can negatively affect performance.

So, if your code does this a lot (or, as in your case, timeouts are long), then you should find a way to cancel your timeouts programmatically when your requests complete. For example:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

/**
 * @param {rp.RequestPromise} request 
 * @param {Number} ms 
 * @returns {Promise<Error>}
 */
const delay = (request, ms) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      request.cancel();
      return reject(new Error("Timeout"))
    }, ms)
    
    request.finally(() => clearTimeout(id))
  }
)

async function main() {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: "https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",
    };

    const request = rp(options);
    const response = await Promise.race([request, delay(request, 500000)]);

    console.log(response)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3301-calling-timeout-unref-with-settimeout-does-not-appear-to-be-a-best-practice-in-node-js.htm

Comment: @StackSlave I was to mention that, but I forgot. Thanks for reminding me, I edited my post.

Comment: Why did you removed cloning thing?

Comment: @jeffbRTC Because I realised that I was wrong. Calling `.then()` does really clone the promise, but also handles it, what I was trying to avoid with it (I tried to avoid marking the promise as 'handled' because, although this code does call `.catch()` on it, doesn't really handle it, just discards the error; so if your code doesn't handle it somewhere else, it should issue a warning, but this way it does not, hence the comment I added there)

Comment: This 100% works and fixes the issue that I have had.   With that said,  I understand Promise.race but don't understand why you send "request" to "delay.'   Wouldn't that be calling "request" twice?  Once in Promise.race and once in 'delay'

Comment: @AndyP No, Promises don't work that way. The `rp()` function call initiates the request immediately, regardless of how its returned promise is used. The promise is just a way to receive and handle the result, but it can't influence the request. Also, promises may be consumed several "listeners"; calling `then` more than once will not repeat the request but hand over the same result to both `then` callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my two cents:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
function Canceller(){
  let interval;
  this.cancellable = (request, milliseconds)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      interval = setTimeout(()=>{
        request.cancel(); reject(new Error('timeout'));
      }, milliseconds);
    });
  }
  this.stopCancel = ()=>{
    clearTimeout(interval); interval = undefined;
    return this;
  }
} 
async function main(){
  try{
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.ipify.org/?format=json'
    }
    const request = rp(options), canceller = new Canceller;
    const response = await Promise.race([request, canceller.cancellable(request, 500000)]);
    if(response === request)canceller.stopCancel();
    console.log(response)
  }catch(e){
    console.log(e)
  }
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an abstraction over other answers,

```
const withTimeout = (millis, promise) => {
    const request = promise;
    
    const timeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let id = setTimeout(
            () => reject(promise.cancel()),
            millis)

        promise
            .then() //Clone the promise (prevents 'handling' the original one)
            .catch(() => { }) //Disregard rejections on this chain
            .then(() => clearTimeout(id))
    })

    return Promise.race([
        request.json(),
        timeout
    ]);
};
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*prevents 'handling' the original one*", but `.then()` is usually pointless on promises. Although it looks like your `promise` parameter is not expecting a standard `Promise`, as you call `.cancel()` and `.json()` methods on it.

Comment: @Bergi That comment made by FZs. Look at the top answer.

Comment: Ah, but [he already corrected it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66895543/revisions).

Answer (score 0):

With a custom promise built on top of the native, it works out of the box:

```
const {CPromise} = require('c-promise2');
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function main() {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      // request with 2sec delay
      url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/7b038025-fc5f-4564-90eb-4373f0721822?mocky-delay=2s"
    };

    const response = await CPromise.from(rp(options)).timeout(1000);

    console.log(response)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e) // CanceledError: timeout
  }
}

main()
```

Or according to your code:

```
const {CPromise} = require('c-promise2');
const rp = require('request-promise');

async function main() {
  try {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      // request with 2sec delay
      url: "https://run.mocky.io/v3/7b038025-fc5f-4564-90eb-4373f0721822?mocky-delay=2s"
    };

    const request = rp(options);
    const response = await CPromise.race([request, CPromise.delay(10000)]);

    console.log(response)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}

main()
```

It will automatically cancel the network requests and/or clear the timer when needed so the node process will exit as soon as one of the promises is settled.